# golang компилирование для хостинга

Tags: golang, build, x86-64

Стоит задача скомпилировать для сайта на Golang программу, которая будет вызываться внутри CGI скрипта. Хостинг не виртуальный, нет возможности на нем компилировать.
При компилировании командой

---

GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o hello_linux_x64

---

создается файл, который работает только на данном ПК.
Пробовал на тестовом сервере скомпилировать, файлы отличаются по размеру. На хостинге тоже эти файлы не запускаются и выдает ошибку:

Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Что удивительно, пробовал компилировать для Windows как 32 так и 64 разрядной, обе программы работали.

Как мне скомпилировать для хостинга.
Если предлагаете вариант с виртуальной машиной, то говорте на какой конкретно можно провести эмуляцию по железу и архитектуре как на хостере, т.к. пробовал уже поднимать виртуалку с Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, компилить и переносить на хостинг - не работает.

Среда разработки:
Architecture:        x86_64
Model name:          Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G620 @ 2.60GHz
ОС:                  Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS x64
Go 1.15.7

Хостинг:
Architecture:        x86_64
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v2 @ 2.60GHz
ОС:                  Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Тестовый сервер:
Architecture:        x86_64
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5420  @ 2.50GHz
ОС:                  Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS 64x
Go 1.15.7

код тестовый самый простой:

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Content-type: text/html \n\n")
    fmt.Printf("<html><body>hello, world</body></html>\n")
}
```

Comment: А зачем это вызывать через CGI? Не проще проксировать запрос на работающий процесс?

Comment: Проксирование, это изящный вариант. Хостер nginx не предоставляет, только апачи да и то только с правкой через .htacess. Потом второй момент, часть сайта на одном движке, а другая дописанная на другом языке. GoLang нужен больше для ускорения части кода. По поводу проксирования, как сделать тогда это проксирование с части сайта из подкаталога к примеру /online/

Comment: Я правильно понял, что бинарники кросс-скомпилированные из-под Windows, работают на Linux, а скомпилированные из-под Linux, не хотят работать на других машинах с Linux?

Comment: Все компилировалось под linux Ubuntu 18.04.для разных платформ. В винде заработал, разлинчых linux нет. Команды для компилирования: ~/work/src/hello# GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 go build -o hello_win86.exe
~/work/src/hello# GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build -o hello_win64.exe
~/work/src/hello# GOOS=linux GOARCH=386 go build -o hello_linux86
~/work/src/hello# GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o hello_linux64

Comment: Понятно. С моей точки зрения, это похоже на баг компилятора. Можете попробовать создать issue [у них на гитхабе](https://github.com/golang/go/issues) с описанием проблемы. Там уже был похожий случай, правда касался он FreeBSD.

Comment: Оу, да у них там вообще [куча issues](https://github.com/golang/go/issues?q=Illegal+instruction) с сообщением *Illegal instruction*.